# How can i use sql in Django 1.8?

Tags: sql, django, python-2.7

I am unable to perform sql operations in django environment. When i use python manage.py sql info, it throws an error unknown command: sql.

What can i do to execute this?

Comment: Please provide additional information by posting you code that causes the error. *What can i do to execute this?* - please show what are you trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, there isn't an `sql` command. Are you looking for [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#dbshell)?

```
python manage.py dbshell
```